# Kubernetes - How to know latest supported API version

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is there a table that will tell me which set of API versions I should be using, given a k8s cluster version? Kubernetes docs always assume I always have a nice, up-to-date cluster (1.12 at time of writing) but platform providers don't always live on this bleeding edge so it can get frustrating quite quickly.

Better yet, is there a `kubectl` command I can run that will let me cluster tell me each resource type and its latest supported API version?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

For getting a list of all the resource types and their latest supported version, run the following:

```
for kind in `kubectl api-resources | tail +2 | awk '{ print $1 }'`; do kubectl explain $kind; done | grep -e "KIND:" -e "VERSION:"
```

It should produce output like

```
KIND:     Binding
VERSION:  v1
KIND:     ComponentStatus
VERSION:  v1
KIND:     ConfigMap
VERSION:  v1
KIND:     Endpoints
VERSION:  v1
KIND:     Event
VERSION:  v1
...
```

As @Rico mentioned, they key is in the `kubectl explain` command. This may be a little fragile since it depends on the format of the printed output, but it works for kubernetes 1.9.6

Also, the information can be gathered in a less efficient way from the kubernetes API docs (with links for each version) found here - https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/#api-reference

Comment: Beware though. Sometimes the same object is available in two different APIs (e.g. currently `Ingress` in `extensions` and `networking.k8s.io`) and it may default to the older (e.g. Ingress shows `extensions/v1beta1`, but `networking.k8s.io/v1beta1` is more appropriate).

Comment: … also the documentation only shows `Ingress` as `networking.k8s.io/v1beta1` from 1.18, but the specification is apparently valid since 1.14.

Comment: script to find all deprecated api versions: https://github.com/dguyhasnoname/k8s-day2-ops/blob/master/upgrade/k8s-deprecations.sh

Comment: If you get an error saying `tail: cannot open '+2' for reading: No such file or directory` try `tail -n 2` instead of `tail +2`

Comment: The API reference pages are confusing to me. How do I see what versions of `HorizontalPodAutoscaler` are supported by k8s version 1.23?

Answer (score 29):

I think `kubectl api-versions` is a simpler alternative:

```html
 kubectl api-versions
admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1
apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
apiregistration.k8s.io/v1
apiregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1
apps/v1
apps/v1beta1
apps/v1beta2
authentication.k8s.io/v1
authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
authorization.k8s.io/v1
authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
autoscaling/v1
autoscaling/v2beta1
autoscaling/v2beta2
batch/v1
batch/v1beta1
certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1
coordination.k8s.io/v1
coordination.k8s.io/v1beta1
events.k8s.io/v1beta1
extensions/v1beta1
networking.k8s.io/v1
networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
node.k8s.io/v1beta1
policy/v1beta1
rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
scheduling.k8s.io/v1
scheduling.k8s.io/v1beta1
storage.k8s.io/v1
storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
v1
```

Comment: That's handy when the name to use is obvious, but how would you know from that output that a Deployment should use extensions/v1beta1 which is very clear from the accepted answer.

Comment: yeah, I agree with ken, this isn't a very good solution to the question that was asked.

Answer (score 13):

That would be the `kubectl explain <resource>` command. For example for pods:

```
$ kubectl explain pod
KIND:     Pod
VERSION:  v1   <==  API version

DESCRIPTION:
     Pod is a collection of containers that can run on a host. This resource is
     created by clients and scheduled onto hosts.

FIELDS:
   apiVersion   <string>
     APIVersion defines the versioned schema of this representation of an
     object. Servers should convert recognized schemas to the latest internal
     value, and may reject unrecognized values. More info:
     https://git.k8s.io/community/contributors/devel/api-conventions.md#resources

...
```

Similarly for deployments:

```
$ kubectl explain deploy
KIND:     Deployment
VERSION:  extensions/v1beta1 <== API Version

DESCRIPTION:
     DEPRECATED - This group version of Deployment is deprecated by
     apps/v1beta2/Deployment. See the release notes for more information.
     Deployment enables declarative updates for Pods and ReplicaSets.

FIELDS:
   apiVersion   <string>
     APIVersion defines the versioned schema of this representation of an
     object. Servers should convert recognized schemas to the latest internal
     value, and may reject unrecognized values. More info:
     https://git.k8s.io/community/contributors/devel/api-conventions.md#resources
...
```

Also, here's the [v1.12 API reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.12/) for example.

Comment: Also you can launch `kubectl proxy` and check api version in swagger.

Answer (score 3):

For kubernetes-1.17.x (different format from what posted above)

```
for i in `kubectl api-resources | grep -v KIND | awk '{print $NF}'`;do kubectl explain ${i} | grep -e "KIND:" -e "VERSION:"; echo '----'; done
```

will show api for each kind

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tool - kubepug as a pre-upgrade check to find out what changed in a given Kubernetes version if you were to upgrade your cluster to that version. Link - https://github.com/rikatz/kubepug

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Move2Kube](https://konveyor.io/move2kube/) and do `move2kube collect` with the Kubernetes cluster in context to get all kind versions supported by the cluster. It gives an ordered list of all versions supported by a kind in an order going from newest to oldest.

It will give you the following information:

```
apiVersion: move2kube.konveyor.io/v1alpha1
kind: ClusterMetadata
metadata:
  name: IBM-IKS
spec:
  storageClasses:
    - default
    - ibmc-block-bronze
    - ibmc-block-custom
    - ibmc-block-gold
    - ibmc-block-retain-bronze
    - ibmc-block-retain-custom
    - ibmc-block-retain-gold
    - ibmc-block-retain-silver
    - ibmc-block-silver
    - ibmc-file-bronze
    - ibmc-file-bronze-gid
    - ibmc-file-custom
    - ibmc-file-gold
    - ibmc-file-gold-gid
    - ibmc-file-retain-bronze
    - ibmc-file-retain-custom
    - ibmc-file-retain-gold
    - ibmc-file-retain-silver
    - ibmc-file-silver
    - ibmc-file-silver-gid
  apiKindVersionMap:
    APIService:
      - apiregistration.k8s.io/v1
    BGPConfiguration:
      - crd.projectcalico.org/v1
    BGPPeer:
      - crd.projectcalico.org/v1
    Binding:
      - v1
    BlockAffinity:
      - crd.projectcalico.org/v1
    CSIDriver:
      - storage.k8s.io/v1
      - storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
    CSINode:
      - storage.k8s.io/v1
      - storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
    CatalogSource:
      - operators.coreos.com/v1alpha1
    CertificateSigningRequest:
      - certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1
    ClusterInformation:
      - crd.projectcalico.org/v1
    ClusterRole:
      - rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
      - rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
    ClusterRoleBinding:
      - rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
      - rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
    ClusterServiceVersion:
      - operators.coreos.com/v1alpha1
    ComponentStatus:
      - v1
    ConfigMap:
      - v1
    ControllerRevision:
      - apps/v1
    CronJob:
      - batch/v1beta1
      - batch/v2alpha1
    CustomResourceDefinition:
      - apiextensions.k8s.io/v1
    DaemonSet:
      - apps/v1
    Deployment:
      - apps/v1
    EndpointSlice:
      - discovery.k8s.io/v1beta1
    Endpoints:
      - v1
    Event:
      - events.k8s.io/v1beta1
      - v1
    FelixConfiguration:
      - crd.projectcalico.org/v1
    GlobalNetworkPolicy:
      - crd.projectcalico.org/v1
    GlobalNetworkSet:
      - crd.projectcalico.org/v1
    HorizontalPodAutoscaler:
      - autoscaling/v1
      - autoscaling/v2beta1
      - autoscaling/v2beta2
    HostEndpoint:
      - crd.projectcalico.org/v1
    IPAMBlock:
      - crd.projectcalico.org/v1
    IPAMConfig:
      - crd.projectcalico.org/v1
    IPAMHandle:
      - crd.projectcalico.org/v1
    IPPool:
      - crd.projectcalico.org/v1
    Ingress:
      - networking.k8s.io/v1
      - networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
      - extensions/v1beta1
    IngressClass:
      - networking.k8s.io/v1
      - networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
    InstallPlan:
      - operators.coreos.com/v1alpha1
    Job:
      - batch/v1
    KubeControllersConfiguration:
      - crd.projectcalico.org/v1
    Lease:
      - coordination.k8s.io/v1beta1
      - coordination.k8s.io/v1
    LimitRange:
      - v1
    LocalSubjectAccessReview:
      - authorization.k8s.io/v1
      - authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
    MutatingWebhookConfiguration:
      - admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1
      - admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1
    Namespace:
      - v1
    NetworkPolicy:
      - networking.k8s.io/v1
    NetworkSet:
      - crd.projectcalico.org/v1
    Node:
      - v1
    Operator:
      - operators.coreos.com/v1
    OperatorGroup:
      - operators.coreos.com/v1
    PersistentVolume:
      - v1
    PersistentVolumeClaim:
      - v1
    Pod:
      - v1
    PodDisruptionBudget:
      - policy/v1beta1
    PodSecurityPolicy:
      - policy/v1beta1
    PodTemplate:
      - v1
    PriorityClass:
      - scheduling.k8s.io/v1beta1
      - scheduling.k8s.io/v1
    RBACSync:
      - ibm.com/v1alpha1
    ReplicaSet:
      - apps/v1
    ReplicationController:
      - v1
    ResourceQuota:
      - v1
    Role:
      - rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
      - rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
    RoleBinding:
      - rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
      - rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
    Secret:
      - v1
    SelfSubjectAccessReview:
      - authorization.k8s.io/v1
      - authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
    SelfSubjectRulesReview:
      - authorization.k8s.io/v1
      - authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
    Service:
      - v1
    ServiceAccount:
      - v1
    StatefulSet:
      - apps/v1
    StorageClass:
      - storage.k8s.io/v1
      - storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
    SubjectAccessReview:
      - authorization.k8s.io/v1
      - authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
    Subscription:
      - operators.coreos.com/v1alpha1
    TokenReview:
      - authentication.k8s.io/v1
      - authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
    ValidatingWebhookConfiguration:
      - admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1
      - admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1
    VolumeAttachment:
      - storage.k8s.io/v1
      - storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
```